# Robotframework:Working with ride,

Tags: robotframework

Collections library is not working in ride(robot framework)not able to use below keywords : " append the list,Combine list"
I am not able to access these keywords..!!
I did imported collections library,still these keywords are not there.

Comment: You should sahre with a erorr log

Comment: `append the list` and `combine list` are not keywords in the collections library. Did you mean `append to list` and `combine lists`? RIDE (or any other editor) won't recognize misspelled keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Your mentioned keywords seem not correct. the Correct keyword : **Append To List** , **Combine Lists** .
Please following the documentation [Collection](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Append%20To%20List)